# Java - Problem override with method inheritance

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, extends

I have the next problem with inheritance in Objects:

-First Class:

```
public class LegalPersonRest extends LegalPerson {}
```

-Second Class:

```
public class Company {

private List<LegalPerson> legalPersons;

}
```

-Third Class:

```
public class CompanyRest extends Company {

@Override
public List<LegalPersonRest> getLegalPersons() {
    return super.getLegalPersons();
}

}
```

In this method getLegalPersons I got the error: attempting to use incompatible return type.

I don't know why if LegalPersonRest extends LegalPerson.

The classes Company and LegalPerson are my domain. (layer domain)

The classes CompanyRest and LegalPersonRest extends the classes of the domain. (layer adapter)

If I change of List to List, I think is wrong because I need used LegalPersonRest.

What's the correct form of inheritance for this case?

Regards,

Comment: I think we get this question most days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to point out in case this was the issue: the super class needs to have the method you are overriding. `Company` doesn't have the method `getLegalPersons()`, so you can't override it. But I think `Company` does have `getLegalPersone()` because you call that method later (please produce a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). The next thing I can think of is that `Company`'s `getLegalPersons()` method doesn't return a `List<LegalPersonRest>`. It might return a list of something else, or another object entirely. Please check the return type to see if it is the same return type as the method in `CompanyRest`.